# Delete nodes at positions divisible by 5 in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to delete every node at positions divisible by 5. With my approach I cannot seem to delete the last node:

```
void removeDivFive(Node* head){
    int count = 0;
    Node* temp = head;
    
    while(temp != NULL){
        count++;
        if(count%5==0){
            if(temp->next != NULL){
                temp->value = temp->next->value;
                temp->next = temp->next->next;
            }
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    
    while(head != NULL){
        cout<<head->value;
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

What I'm doing is copying the value of the next node to the current one and changing the pointer to the next next node. By doing this I cannot delete the last node if the list has 10 nodes.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: First off, you are leaking the nodes you "remove".  You need to actually destroy them since they are no longer being used. Second, regarding your actual problem, what do you thing `temp->next` points at when the last node is at a position divisible by 5? *Nothing*! So you aren't even attempting to do anything with that node.

Comment: Unrelated. `removeDivFive` promises to return a `Node *`, but doesn't. That'll bite sooner or later.

Comment: @user4581301 ah, I returned `head` in the original file, but decided to add the `while` loop to print for ease of understanding.

Comment: You aren't counting the nodes you remove. So at position 4 you remove node 5, then at position 9 (used to be 10) you remove node 11, at position 14 (used to be 16) you remove node 17.

Comment: @RemyLebeau When the last node is at a position divisible by 5 then `temp->next` will point that exactly that last node. The problem is the count is wrong since deleted nodes are skipped.

Comment: @Goswin that's better than some alternatives. Once you remove the fifth node, there's probably a new fifth node, so you'll have to remove that, which means likely there's another new fifth node...

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow "*When the last node is at a position divisible by 5 then `temp->next` will point that exactly that last node*" - No, it doesn't. That is my point.  Look again.  `temp` points at the last node.  `temp->next` points at `NULL`.

Comment: Side note: One of the best ways to wrangle linked lists is to help visualize them by drawing pictures. If you take that to the extreme and draw every step, you'll have a fantastic tool when it comes time to debug. You follow along with the pictures as you step through the program with the debugger. When you catch the program doing something unexpected, you know exactly where and what it should have done instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  The `count` is generally wrong all along the list. If it's changed to `count%4==0` and you remove the `temp->value = temp->next->value;` it does the right thing (ignoring memory leakage). But I see what you mean, the `value` thing can't work for the last element in the list but it's doesn't work with the fixed count anyway.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You did see my comment about the deleted nodes not getting counted? So `count%4==0` becomes true every 5 nodes. It fires at position 4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, ... where you have to `delete temp->next`. That way it works and the last node problem doesn't occur.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Both ways work. I added your way to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you are leaking the nodes you "remove". You need to actually destroy them since they are no longer being used.

Now, regarding your actual problem - what do you thing `temp->next` points at when the last node in the list is at a position divisible by 5? *NOTHING*! Thus, `if (temp->next != NULL)` evaluates as false, so you aren't even attempting to do anything with that last node, you just skip past it, which is why you are not removing it.

For every 5th node, you are copying the value of the *next* node into the current node, and then pointing the current node to *skip* the next node.  In other words, you are not removing the 5th, 10th, 15th, etc nodes at all.  You are actually removing the 6th, 11th, 16th, etc nodes instead.  You need to remove the *current* node instead of the *next* node.

Which also means, you need to keep track of the *previous* node in the list so that you can re-link its `next` pointer to point at the *next* node that follows the *current* node being removed.

Try something more like this instead:

```
void removeDivFive(Node* head){
    int count = 0;
    Node *temp = head, *prev = NULL, *next;
    
    while (temp != NULL){
        ++count;
        next = temp->next;
        if ((count % 5) == 0){
            if (prev != NULL) {
                prev->next = next;
            }
            delete temp;
        }
        else {
            prev = temp;
        }
        temp = next;
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/liO18K)

---

Alternatively (as [described by @GoswinvonBrederlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72552346/#comment128163397_72552346) in comments):

```
void removeDivFive(Node* head){
    int count = 0;
    Node *temp = head, *next;
 
    while (temp != NULL){
        ++count;
        if ((count  %4) == 0){
            if (temp->next != NULL){
                next = temp->next->next;
                delete temp->next;
                temp->next = next;
            }
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/DEelzY)

Comment: bruh how, I've been throwing things at the wall and seeing what sticks for the last hour. Thanks a lot for the reply, seems quite understandable as well!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments the deleted node isn't counted. So you need to delete a node every 4 counts instead of every 5. And if you use `count%4 == 0` then the first time `temp` will point at node 4 and you want to delete the 5th node. So no need for `temp->value = temp->next->value;`, just remove the next node. Then next time around when `count = 8` then `temp` will point at node 9. So again `temp->next` is the node to remove. ...

So the condition always fires for the node before the 5th, which is perfect for removing it.

```
void removeDivFive(Node* head){
    int count = 0;
    for (Node* temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next) {
        count++;
        if(count%4==0){
            if(temp->next != NULL){
                Node *t = temp->next;
                temp->next = t->next;
                delete t;
            }
        }
    }
    
    while(head != NULL){
        cout<<head->value;
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `count=16`?

Comment: Then temp points at node 19 and temp->next is 20 and gets removed